# Get the last occurring letter in a string contain letters and non-letters

Tags: php, regex

I have one string like below.

```
$string = '2346#$ABSC$%#@#234567';
```

I want the last character from this string that is not numeric or a special character. It may only be a letter (in uppercase or lowercase).

In this case, I need only "C" from this string.

I have tried this formula:

```
substr($string, -1);
```

Comment: `echo substr(preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/i', '', $string), -1);`

Comment: And if you get an error `Undefined variable: ABSC in ...` it's because your string `"2346#$ABSC$%#@#234567"` contains `$ABSC` and is wrapped in double quotes, meaning it will try to interpolate a variable called `$ABSC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into regular expressions using something like [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

An expression like this would match:

```
/([a-z])[^a-z]*$/i
```

It means:

- `([a-z])` Capture an a-z character (the `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive)
- `[^a-z]*$` followed by 0 or more non a-z characters until the end of the string

See [an example](https://regex101.com/r/iX6uN7/2).

Comment: [It would match the first match, not the last one](https://regex101.com/r/lF9vR0/1). [`/([a-z])[^a-z]+$/i` is better, I believe](https://regex101.com/r/lF9vR0/2).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Aiaiai, you're right, I forgot to add that. I used a `*` instead as there might be no non-letter at the end as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here I just replace everything expect `a-zA-Z` with an empty string. After this I just access the last character)

```
<?php

    $string = '2346#$ABSC$%#@#234567';
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
    echo $string[strlen($string)-1];

?>
```

output:

```
C
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper regex is: `([a-z])[^a-z]*$`

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated on this answer, use a regex pattern to isolate the last letter which is only followed by zero or more non-letters then the end of the string.

No capture groups are needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VeKjM))

```
$string = '2346#$ABSC$%#@#234567';

echo preg_match('/[a-z](?=[^a-z]*$)/i', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : 'not found';
// outputs: C
```